# AllJoynChat sample - directory not found for option '-L/build/Debug-iphoneos'

Tags: alljoyn

I tried to build the AllJoynChat sample and got the following error message:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am using Xcode 7.2 and iOS 9.2 SDK. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your the build cannot find openssl library.

The following steps need to be followed exactly as below:

1. Unzip the AllJoyn SDK package to a folder on your development system.
2. Download and copy the OpenSSL source into a separate folder on your development system, not under the AllJoyn SDK.
3. Navigate to the OpenSSL source top folder in Finder, and copy the openssl.xcodeproj folder you downloaded from GitHub into this folder.
4. Open the openssl.xcodeproj in Xcode.
5. In Xcode, build the crypto target (libssl.a and libcrypto.a) for each
   combination of configuration (debug|release) and platform (iphoneos|iphonesimulator) that you need for your iOS project by selecting Product->Build For->(your desired configuration).
6. Create a new folder called "build" under the top-level OpenSSL folder created in step 1.
7. Locate your OpenSSL build products folders (i.e.: Debug-iphoneos) in the
   /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXXXXXXXXXX-openssl/Build/Products folder, and copy all the - folders, like Debug-iphoneos, to the build
   folder created in step 6.
8. You should now have a folder structure similar to this containing libssl and libcrypto
   for each $(CONFIGURATION)-$(PLATFORM_NAME) you built in step 5:

   openssl-1.0.1c

   ```
       build
             Debug-iphoneos
                   libssl.a
                   libcrypto.a

             Debug-iphonesimulator
                   libssl.a
                   libcrypto.a
   ```
9. Define an environment variable OPENSSL_ROOT= 
   This environment variable needs to be present whenever you build projects using the AllJoyn SDK.

   9a. For Mac OS X 10.7 to 10.9, to set the environment variable, open a Terminal window and type the
       following:

   ```
   launchctl setenv OPENSSL_ROOT <path to top level folder containing openssl>
   ```

   **Restart XCode.**

   9b. With Mac OS X 10.10, environment variable processing changed. Most importantly, OPENSSL_ROOT
       must be defined before launching Xcode (Xcode will not pick up new or changed variables
       after launching). Therefore, to set the environment variable, open a Terminal window and type
       the following:

   ```
   launchctl setenv OPENSSL_ROOT <path to top level folder containing openssl>
   sudo killall Finder
   sudo killall Dock
   ```

   **Restart XCode.**

If you have already done the above check step 9 since the step differs for different version of OS X and you may be on the latest version for which the instructions have not been updated yet.

Comment: Hi, I am currently stuck on step 5. When I tried to build the crypto target, I got the following error messages: 1) /DerivedData/openssl-ashmflfsadzbicgbnvfolnvublpl/Build/Intermediates/openssl.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/crypto.build/Script-9038ACD812DCAC96004FA0D0.sh: line 66: ./config: No such file or directory 2) cp: libcrypto.a: No such file or directory 3) cp: libssl.a: No such file or directory etc.

Comment: Which xcode project are you using to build Openssl ? 
Is this the one: https://github.com/sqlcipher/openssl-xcode?

Comment: Thanks, NikofTime. I managed to build the openssl.xcodeproj successfully. However, I still cannot build the AllJoynChat sample. I am getting: ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/build/Debug-iphonesimulator'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/***/Downloads/alljoyn-ios/core/alljoyn/alljoyn_objc/samples/iOS/AllJoynChat/../../../../build/darwin/x86_64/iphonesimulator/Debug/dist/cpp/lib'
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Did you restart XCode after you did 

1. launchctl setenv OPENSSL_ROOT <path to top level folder containing openssl>
2. sudo killall Finder
3. sudo killall Dock
4. Restart XCode

Comment: Yes, I did that but still the same results. Also, I looked at the darwin folder and couldn't find the x86_64 subfolder within it. I found only: arm, arm64, armv7, armv7s, i386, x86. Could that perhaps be the problem?

Comment: Well you are trying to access the -lssl for a real device so x86_64 wouldn't matter unless your build settings is explicitly trying to build it. Can you try setting OPENSSL_ROOT and then starting Xcode from the same terminal so that it has guaranteed access to this environment variable.